# Quicktron company - Mobile robots (Equivalent of Kiva Systems?)

Tags: mobile-robot, multi-agent

Since some months on many websites, I read and I have seen images of the Alibaba (the Chinese e-commerce giant) warehouses. One example is the following article:

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4754078/China-s-largest-smart-warehouse-manned-60-robots.html

It seems interesting and it seems really the same Amazon is doing with its Kiva Systems. **The equivalent of Kiva Systems here should be a company called Quicktron** but I am not able to find anything about it on the internet.

Someone of you has any knowledge about this company? A website?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* kalmanIsAGameChanger, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Indeed it was not a shopping question at all. I just wanted to know if someone had info about this company which seems doing a lot of interesting work but it is hard to track. They turned my question into a shopping one but this was not my intent.

Answer (score 4):

The company is called Flashhold, here is the link to the website:
http://www.flashhold.com/

They raised more than 29M$ in aseries B funding recently and seem to gain a lot of traction
https://www.chinamoneynetwork.com/2017/03/30/cainiao-softbank-lead-29m-round-in-chinese-logistic-robot-firm-flashhold

Hope this helps, do not hesitate to exchange back if you have more info.

Comment: Therefore, Quicktron is the name of the robot or what?

Comment: For comparison (with a bit of opinion) you can look at this forbes blog https://www.forbes.com/sites/stevebanker/2016/01/11/robots-in-the-warehouse-its-not-just-amazon/2/#39df178f352d